# How do you get a GET query from a URL?

Tags: javascript, url, get

I'd done it before with javascript, I think, but I don't remember how now.  I have a url like http://www.example.com/cow.php?says=moo and I want to get the "moo" from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a function that returns array of variables from the URL

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }

    return vars;
}
```

Comment: I think I also did it from a form, if that helps any.

Comment: do you mean you also did it from a post method?  If it is a post, javascript can not parse it.

Answer (score 1):

Its called Query String and this page has some good explanation. 
http://ilovethecode.com/Javascript/Javascript-Tutorials-How_To-Easy/Get_Query_String_Using_Javascript.shtml

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/jsuri/) is a standalone URI parsing library that can handle any URI you can imagine (according to the author) and allows you to work with URI's like you would a JS object (which is nice)

Examples:

```
uri = new jsUri('http://user:pass@www.test.com:81/index.html?q=books#fragment');

uri.protocol(); // http
uri.userInfo(); // user:pass
uri.host();     // www.test.com
uri.port();     // 81
uri.path();     // /index.html
uri.query();    // q=books
uri.anchor();   // fragment
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have a native way of doing this. Most functions I've seen involve passing the name of the parameter you are looking for and then using RegEx to get it from the URL. Using the function from:

[Get URL Parameters using JavaScript](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html)

Your code would look like:

```
var saysVal = gup('says');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery there is a plugin for this:

https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser

Using it is quite easy too.

If you want to fetch the query string from the current url:

`jQuery.url.attr("query")`

If you want to fetch the query string from another url:

`jQuery.url.setUrl("http://example.com?id=123").attr("query")`

The plugin can also be used to parse other parts of a URI such as:

- protocol (http, https, ...)
- host
- anchor

etc..

- Christian